# Are questions about Hillary, Bill and Donald considered off-topic, at the moment?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

I saw some contentious activity (questions, comments) earlier today, e.g., a user that wanted to verify the taped conversation of Trump's words about what he did / does to women because of his fame.

Are questions about Bill, Hillary and Donald considered off-topic for the moment?

Thanks,

Comment: We don't do "temporary" rules, questions will be held to the same standard as always. Regardless of the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

There are no special rules about US politics, but you can imagine they will be getting more scrutiny from all the users, given their sensitive nature.

See the tags for examples of questions about [bill-clinton](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bill-clinton), [hillary-clinton](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hillary-clinton), [donald-trump](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump).

I think you are talking about this [(now deleted) question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35439/) which wasn't about US politics in particular, was closed as unclear, asked an unanswerable question, failed to use [respectful language](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/892/revisions), was attracting "Low Quality" flags and didn't look like it could be saved, so it was deleted as a broken window.